Minimum RAM for a LZString decompressor
In an embedded system where RAM is at premium, I need to decompress a LZString-compressed piece of data of roughly 1kByte max, producing less than 2kByte of (ASCII JSON) characters when decompressed. The compressed data is encoded by this particular LZString*. No substitute!
What's a minimum RAM budget?
Implementations in various languages abound, but all those I reviewed use data structures which RAM usage is not easily bounded, like C++ std::unordered_map or Python dictionaries. I'm considering writing a C implementation, and wonder how I bound the RAM budget.

* I seems: compress in it's original variant which output consists of possibly invalid UTF-16 characters, which I'll get as pairs of bytes in little-endian order. Equivalently IMHO, I need to decompress compressToUint8Array. These details won't much change the RAM usage.

Does it have to be LZString that you pointed to?  Or any compression scheme?   I don't have time to dig around to find the exact information, but the keil/armcc compiler has the option to compress the .init data that gets expanded during startup before main().   I don't know their algorithm, but maybe it can provide something smaller than these bigger algorithms that don't care about runtime.  Of course, the other option is to 'roll your own'

Bummer.  I got nothing except maybe look into ETL (embedded template library) and maybe the unordered map implementation isn't as bad as you think?

Are you asking for the minimum necessary to decompress at all, or the maximum that could possibly be used? These are quite different values.

Did you consider to write your own decompressor? (Please [edit] your question to add new information and clarifications. This is not a forum.)
